# Deleting table contents in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one table is having 1.5 crore (15 million) records and other table is having 1.2 lac (120k) records. I have 2 GB of RAM allocated to MySQL.

common column in both the tables is "id".

```
mysql> desc day_tran;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| card_number     | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ATM_id          | varchar(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| responder       | varchar(1)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| response_code   | varchar(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Amount          | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Time            | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| RR_number       | varchar(14) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tran_code       | varchar(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reversal_reason | varchar(2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date            | varchar(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tlf_date        | varchar(6)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.74 sec)

mysql> desc reversal;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id              | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| card_number     | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ATM_id          | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| responder       | varchar(1)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| response_code   | varchar(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Amount          | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Time            | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| RR_number       | varchar(14) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| tran_code       | varchar(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| reversal_reason | varchar(2)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| date            | varchar(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| tlf_date        | varchar(6)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

Now I need to delete all the rows that are present in reversal table from day_tran table.

I tried some of the ways for deleting and creating new table with rest of the results but I end up no where.

Comment: What ever delete statement I am using it is taking hours to execute but nothing is happening.

Comment: 1. I want to delete rows from day_tran table

Comment: 2. millions of rows exists in the table and RAM is very limited so I need best query. sub queries are resource hungry.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM day_tran d INNER JOIN reversal r ON d.id = r.id WHERE d.id = r.id
```

should do it.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
 for the right syntax to use near 'd INNER JOIN reversal r ON d.id = r.id WHERE d.id = r.id' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query. No need for a WHERE statement or any "SUB SELECT"s:

```
DELETE FROM reversal r INNER JOIN day_trans d ON r.id = d.id;
```

And you're fine.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use delete query as below. if you want to delete all records based on the `id` which presents commonly in both table

```
 DELETE FROM reversal r inner join day_tran d on r.id = d.id
```

Comment: did you literally copy my incorrect answer before i updated it? he wants to delete from day_tran records that exist in reversal

Comment: JOIN + WHERE STATEMENT? I think just a join does this job, because you get only entries with `r.id = d.id`

Comment: This will probably only take a couple of weeks.

Comment: @Sebi2020 Sorry mymistake i slightly confused.. now i edited my answer